# Two Year Old Won't Toilet Outside of Home

Tags: toddler, potty-training

I have a two year old who is still in nappies and she will not do a poop outside the comfort of her own home.  This is despite spending two days a week at daycare (she loves going to daycare and sometimes asks to go when it's not a daycare day).  She's not toilet trained yet (though we have begun some work on this) and this has been happening for at least six to twelve months.

Is this normal?  Is there anything we can do to help her feel comfortable enough to poo at daycare?

Comment: What is a 'nappie'?

Comment: @Gryphoenix Another term for diaper.

Comment: @Erica huh...new one for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some children value privacy and comfort when trying to have a bowel movement. You might observe if at home your daughter likes to go into the other room or a playhouse to do her business. It's quite possible the daycare doesn't have anywhere private enough for her to be comfortable.

If privacy isn't her concern, you may try to find out if she's prone to constipation. Perhaps she isn't drinking enough at preschool and without more fluids she may be unable to poop.

Comment: She does normally go out of sight for a poop, so that may be it.

Comment: Did this end up sobbing your problem?

Comment: I think that this is probably part of the reason she won't poop anywhere but home but it didn't really get her pooping elsewhere.  I accepted this answer because I found it helpful.